# How to connect Creative GigaWorks ProGamer G550W wireless speakers through a serial port

Tags: wireless, speakers, serial-port

These connect through a device on a serial port transmitting audio signal via wi-fi. The traditional jack is on "the other" end of the system. 
I could not find anything on the Creative Labs website regaring linux setup, neither on the Internet. I haven't used them yet, even on Windows (found them at work). 
Any idea how to go about connecting these?

You can see the speakers here: http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/new-generation-pc-5-1-speaker-systems,1526-4.html

**EDIT**: The question was based on a wrong assumption that these speakers connect through a serial port which makes it invalid but I am leaving it here for others, there is actually nothing complicated in connecting G550W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no serial port involved anywhere in the G550W system, and it should work just as well with any computer regardless of operating system. The wireless connection is only for the rear-left/rear-right speakers:

[image]

What you are probably referring to is this port on the back of the subwoofer:

[image]

The audio from your computer is input via cables to the inputs on the left side of the subwoofer.

That is NOT a serial port, but a proprietary DB-15 connector used to connect ONLY the control box/wireless transmitter:

[image]

The wireless receiver is set up on the other side, to which you connect the rear-left and rear-right speakers:

[image]

Comment: Thanks izx, you made me realize that I was working on a wrong assumption that if the DB-15 fits into a serial port it is the right way, not so then, I'll edit the question.